# What resistance/load do battery testers (AA or AAA) use in ohms?

Tags: resistors, test-equipment

I am trying to find out what size resistors an AA or AAA battery tester would use?
I have tried searching but am unable to find an answer.

I mean testing alkaline and NiMH 1.5 V and 1.2 V batteries, and by battery testers I mean the devices that normally show whether the battery is good, low, or needs replacing.

Basically I am trying to determine what size resistor I should use to test the batteries mentioned earlier, and by size I mean ohms and watts.

Comment: What is a battery tester? Do you mean life of the battery?

Comment: What kind of battery? Alkaline, zinc-carbon, NiMh, Lithium? More information needed.

Comment: I meant testing alkaline and ni-mh 1.5volt and 1.2 volt batteries

Answer (score 4):

I've used a 10 Ω 5 W resistor in the past and it works well for testing both Zinc-Carbon and Alkaline cells - both "AA" and "AAA".

You will have a current up to 160 mA which is enough to load the cell and show its true voltage at that current level.

A new cell will have a voltage exceeding 1.5 Vdc (often above 1.6 Vdc); a used but still usable cell will have a voltage between 1.2 to 1.5 Vdc; a weak cell will have a voltage between 1.0 to 1.2 Vdc.

A cell with a loaded voltage less than 1.0 Vdc is considered to be dead. Some stuff might run from it, but not for long.

Comment: Thanks for answer but how do you arrive at the 160mA please

Comment: I = V / R. Max voltage is about 1.6 Vdc, resistor is 10 Ohms.

Comment: ok but thats with a known voltage (fully charged) i assume but if battery has been used the voltage would have dropped and thats what i want to measure

Comment: I take it that you want to know at which current level a battery's nominal discharge voltage is defined? I suspect there could be some standard defining this for AA and AAA batteries. Some kind of reference load is needed to compare batteries from different manufacturers.

Comment: But if you just want to know if the battery is good enough to power a specific device, I suppose you would ideally select a resistor such that the current is the same as the device would consume. Note that smaller resistors can lead to large current and high power, which could make the battery tester hot or burn out its resistor if it isn't rated for the resulting power.

Comment: thanks for replies but battery testers surely do not select a resistor they must just use a set size which is what i would like to know so i can test batteries under load using a multimeter

Answer (score 1):

I've always used 100 Ω (in series) when I test batteries.  It's not very scientific, but since I always use the same setup, it provides useful information to me.

Comment: Place a resistor across the battery that will draw a reasonable amount of current (ideally equal to the actual load the battery will see in service) and measure the voltage. This is exactly what is done in commercial battery testers.

Comment: @TomKreutz could you expand your answer and show how you measure batteries with a resistor?

Comment: My 100 ohm resistor is in series with the battery.

Answer (score 1):

I have used my Radio Shack battery tester for years. It has an analog meter marked Replace, ?, and Good. It has a 10 Ω load for AA and AAA cells.

Answer (score 0):

The 1.5 V battery test setting on my multimeter indicates an approximate current draw of 50 mA from which I assume (by Ohm's law) that the load resistance is 30 Ω.