# What is the meaning of the amp measurement of a battery?

Tags: multimeter

Configuration:

- Black probe: Connected to COM
- Red probe: Connected to 10A
- Multimeter set to A DC

Given a rechargeable 2000mA NiMH AA battery at 1.25v it measures 8.0A. Did the multimeter try to pull 10A from the battery but measured that the battery could only provide 8.0A?

Comment: Did you connect red probe to BAT+ and black probe to BAT- ?

Comment: Yes, red is connected to positive and black to negative.

Comment: Congratulations! You shorted your battery with your DMM! Joke aside, `Did the multimeter try to pull 10A from the battery but measured that the battery could only provide 8.0A?` Yes, the DMM tried to draw as much current as possible (because the battery is basically shorted), but it was limited to 8A by the shunt resistor of the DMM and the output resistance of your battery. I don't know what kind of battery (chemical, capacity, etc) you have but you must be lucky, because this could have been ended with fire or explosion. What did you try to measure, actually?

Comment: You are lucky you didn't try that on a charged LIon battery. If you were lucky, the fuse in the multimeter would blow before the meter was destroyed or the battery exploded!

Comment: The multimeter tried to pull as much current as the battery can possibly provide. If this was, for instance, a car battery, that would be hundreds of amps. The 10 A figure is a *rating*; you're the one responsible for making sure it's not more than 10 A.

Comment: @RohatKılıç From what I've seen online this is a way to test the strength of a rechargeable AA battery. For example, new ones measure 8A to 9A while an old one might be 1.0A or less.

Comment: @JamesAdkison You got some pretty terrible advice from the internet, then.

Comment: To be clear, does it matter that I only have contact with the battery for a fraction of a second instead of maintaining the connection for a long period of time?

Comment: `From what I've seen online this is a way to test the strength of a rechargeable AA battery.` It should be something like *"It's strong enough if it doesn't explode"*. Terrible way of testing, sorry. Anyway. `To be clear, does it matter that I only have contact with the battery for a fraction of a second instead of maintaining the connection for a long period of time?` It does and it doesn't. Depends on a lot of factors such as charge level, temperature, chemistry, etc. The maximum current that can be drawn from the battery should be specified somewhere, but I don't think it's higher than 6A.

Comment: I've updated my question to have the details I know about the battery: 2000mA NiMH 1.2v AA.

Do you have a link to an existing resource or question/answer that would be the right way to test if a battery is "good" or should be discarded?

Comment: Drawing some current and measuring the voltage at the same time is the way to go. A test current of 8A-10A would definitely destroy the battery, or at least seriously harm it. Drawing a test current between C/2 and 2C (1A to 4A in your case), and measuring the voltage at the same time to see if it's within the acceptable limits (1.5V to 1.2V, depending on the charging level) is a safer way.

Comment: Thanks. I also found this [question and answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/179307/316347). Would you agree that this describes what you're saying, except they are using 160mA for the load?

Comment: The whole point of the current measurement design in multimeters is that they should add as little series resistance as possible to the circuit, to affect the drawn current as little as possible. They'll be measuring current over some resistor with a tiny value.

Comment: For measuring the "state" of a battery, one can use a circuit that draws some "high" current (begin with a reasonable value, then greater until you notice a "change"), but in an adjustable short time (say one ms every second). Measurements are done within this short time (peak current, voltage of battery). The variable of interest is the ratio delta (Vbat) / delta (current) = Internal impedance.

Comment: You shorted the battery with a 10A fuse and multimeter shunt resistance. Fortunately the battery did not provide enough current into shunt resistance to make more than 8A flow, but don't short circuit the batteries. If the AA battery had been fully charged or had been a D cell, it would have blown the 10A fuse in the multimeter.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers have stated that you shouldn't do it, but not what you actually did:

What you did was you short-circuited the battery and measured the current through the short circuit. Your battery was able to put 8 amps through a short circuit.

There's no need to think of it as "multimeter tried to pull".

Some types of batteries can explode when short-circuited, hence the danger.

Answer (score 1):

What you did, depending on battery chemistry, was very bad: the consequences could have been an explosion or fire.

Testing a battery of any type would be in this fashion:

1. apply a known rated load for a given time (rated to some fraction of the battery capacity and AH rating), vehicle lead acid batteries (trucks etc) can provide 1000A or more so make sure the loads are chosen suitably.
2. measure the voltage, current and time.

Calculate the result as needed. Repeat at various intervals of time and / or voltage - be aware of voltage and current limits for the type of battery tested.

This procedure must be tailored to the battery chemistry under test, what is valid for one battery may not be safe for another. Fuses etc should be used liberally as well as ppe (personal protective equipment).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to measure the internal impedance of the battery (here limited to 200 A) and/or the maximum current that the battery could "give",  one could use a circuit like this (**be aware of "safety" ... and power on the resistor and active devices**),
this circuit can sink 1000 A if the battery is in very good conditions).
Adjust pulse (100 us or less) width and period, with a very low "Duty Cycle" ( D < 0.001).

NB: I show the behavior with a **"ramp"**, which should be preferably a **"pulse"**.
An MCU should be used to measure the variables needed for calculating impedance.

[image]